# Can not find basic class weblogic.Deployer

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh, deployment, weblogic

Deploy weblogic using jenkins without jenkins plugin.

jenkins weblogic plugin use this command. So I try use it.

```
/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -cp /root/wls12210/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -debug -stage -remote -verbose -upload -name testPage -source /root/.jenkins/workspace/WebLogic/target/testPage.war -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://127.0.0.1:7001 -user {ID} -password {password} -deploy
```

But If I use this command not use plugin but only raw command, there is error.

> error: Cannot find basic class weblogic.Deployer or cannot load weblogic.Deployer.

above error evoke as korean language, so I translated to english.
under error is jenkins error part.

> [WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - ARTIFACT UNDEPLOYED SUCCESSFULLY. 
>   [WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - DEPLOYING ARTIFACT... $
>   /bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -cp
>   /root/wls12210/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer
>   -debug -stage -remote -verbose -upload -name testPage -source /root/.jenkins/workspace/WebLogic/target/testPage.war -targets
>   AdminServer -adminurl t3://127.0.0.1:7001 -user {id} -password
>   {passwd} -deploy [WeblogicDeploymentPlugin] - ARTIFACT DEPLOYED
>   SUCCESSFULLY. [INFO]
>   [INFO] DEPLOYMENT SUCCESS [INFO]
>
> SSH: Connecting from host [localhost.localdomain]
>
> SSH: Connecting with configuration [weblogic] ...
>
> SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command[
>   /bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -cp /root/wls12210/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer
>   -debug -stage -remote -verbose -upload -name testPage -source /root/.jenkins/workspace/WebLogic/target/testPage.war -targets
>   AdminServer -adminurl t3://127.0.0.1:7001 -user {id} -password
>   {passwd} -deploy
>
> error: Cannot find basic class weblogic.Deployer or cannot load weblogic.Deployer.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [building](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/client/jarbuilder.html) `wlfullclient.jar` and putting that on your classpath instead? `weblogic.jar` doesn't have any of the ancillary libraries that you'll probably need.

Answer (score 1):

Better load the weblogic environment first, it will load all the weblogic related classes you may need:

According to the path you showed, run this in command line before you try to start the java virtual machine:

```
". /root/wls12210/wlserver/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh"
```